# opera and box-shadow inset on active state

Tags: css, opera

take a look at this **[button](http://jsbin.com/ecaluw/2)**

In Chrome this looks fine but switching to opera you can not see the box-shadow when the button is pressed (:active). This problem only occurs when the box-shadow on :active state is set to inset i.e. like this: `box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000 inset;`

Anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: A simpler test case that also doesn't work in Opera: http://jsbin.com/ecaluw/5. Any `box-shadow` that's `inset` doesn't seem to work on a `button` in Opera.

Comment: haha @thirtydot I'm just playing around with it and finding these stuff. And yeah it seems that the inset is not supported, yet it say's here that inset is supported since 10.5 https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/-moz-box-shadow#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some border radius:

```
    border-radius: 1px;
```

with that, it works.

Comment: seems like this problem only happens with the button and input tag